# How to exclude specific Solr spellchecking results

Tags: solr, spell-checking

We got the problem that we get spellchecking results that are technically correct but not suitable for the context of the input term.

For example the user searches for "ventilator" and the spellchecker returns "vibrator" as the corrected term.

We could remove the value "vibrator" from the possible results but if someone misspells "vibrator" we should return the corrected term.

Is it possible to exclude specific mappings (e.g. "ventilator" > "vibrator")?

The current config:

solrconfig.xml:

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text_spell</str>
    <lst name="spellchecker">
        <str name="name">de</str>
        <str name="field">spellcheck_de</str>
        <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
        <str name="buildOnOptimize">true</str>
    </lst>
```

And the Field config from schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="text_spell_de" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can stuff like 'exclude terms that are less frequent than X' on the index, and the like. But if you want to 'exclude term X when serving suggestions for term Y only' then no, you can't.